# Java - Fetch key from HashMap Single Key Multiple Values (Reverse Map)

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a HashMap defined with something like this:

`Map<Foo, List<Bar>> = new HashMap();`

I am trying to do a reverse search of the Hashmap using the `Bar` to get the `Foo`.

I am wanting to do something like this:

```
if(ArrayListBar.contains(bar)) {
    return Foo;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Is this achievable in HashMap or is there a better way to deal with this without using the HashMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Map iteration.

```
private Foo getKeyByValue(Map<Foo, List<Bar>> map, Bar bar){
    for (Map.Entry<Foo, List<Bar>> entry : map.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getValue().contains(bar)){
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    } 
  return null;
}
```

You iterate for each entry on the map and you return the Key when the array list contains the entered bar value.

Note that your Bar class should implement the equals method so the `entry.getValue().contains(bar)` can be evaluated if the bar in the List with the bar on the method input are different objects.

Update: Added missing `return null` statement when no map element is found.

Comment: *Compile error:* Missing `return` for when not found.

Comment: Java 8 Stream equivalent: `return map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().contains(bar)).findFirst().map(Entry::getKey).orElse(null)`

Comment: @Ioannis Is there a data structure that does it without these many iterations or does it better than this?

Comment: @KillerBeast This is the simplest solution, as you have to search into the map. You cannot avoid the iteration. What do you mean by better? You mean faster? There are alternatives when you have Big Data (millions of entries in your map). For example, Hadoop and Spark does this better by using MapReduce and processes large volumes of data in parallel by dividing the work into a set of independent tasks run in multiple nodes / threads. MapReduce is not a data structure but a programming model.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach can be different under different circumstances.

You can do it by iterating the map and checking whether the list of each entry contains the value or not. But that's Ok only if the map is not too big and the lists in it or either not too big or sorted.

But if the size of the map is big or the lists are big and not sorted and you need to do multiple lookups, it is better to create a reverse map Map.
In that case you have to make sure the hashkey and equals method of Bar are implemented correctly.
If the same value (Bar) can be in multiple lists for different keys (Foo), the reverse map might also require a list of values: Map>.

Depending on the situation, you can create the reverse map while building the original map or afterwards when doing the first lookup and cache it for reuse in later lookups.
When thread safety is involved, it is preferred to create it when creating the original map because in that case you don't need to worry about thread safety of the lookup method which is a problem when creating the reverse map during the first lookup.